# AWS SAM lambda authorizer internet access

Tags: python, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

Just adding to aws sam cli hello world example and trying to add lambda authorizer:

```
MyAuthFunction:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    CodeUri: ./python
    Handler: auth/authorizer.lambda_handler
    Runtime: python3.8
```

My lambda needs to get a public key from my tenant so I need an external get call to get it:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
  ...
  print("getting pub key from", 'https://%s/pem' % os.environ['AUTH_DOMAIN'])
  pub_key = requests.get('https://%s/pem' % os.environ['AUTH_DOMAIN'])
  ...
```

Every time I hit the lambda it gets timed out:

```
Function 'MyAuthFunction' timed out after 3 seconds
```

Am I missing something here? I feel like my lambda doesn't have access to the internet

Answer (score 0):

You should increase [Timeout](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-function.html#sam-function-timeout), from **default 3 seconds** to whatever is required for your function to work successful (max 15 min).

For example:

```
MyAuthFunction:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    CodeUri: ./python
    Handler: auth/authorizer.lambda_handler
    Runtime: python3.8
    Timeout: 60 # one minute
```

Comment: @Wildhammer Still timing out after 3 seconds?

Comment: I tried increasing the timeout but like I said I suspect my lambda does not have access to the internet.

Comment: @Wildhammer Is it placed in a VPC?

Comment: No, unless sam cli puts everything in a VPC-like place when testing locally.